# Apache tag is frequently misapplied

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, ambiguous-tags

According to its Tag Wiki Summary, [apache](/questions/tagged/apache) is about:

> The Apache HTTP Server, commonly referred to as Apache [...]

In the Java environment (and not only there) there are [*tons* of Apache projects](https://projects.apache.org/indexes/language.html) that are relevant to Stack Overflow questions: Tomcat, Apache Commons (and many, many sub-projects), Apache Derby, FOP, ...

The problem is that many times questions are tagged wrong:

- [they are tagged as](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache+derby) [apache](/questions/tagged/apache) **and** [derby](/questions/tagged/derby) (cleaned as of 2013-10-07) or
- [tagged as](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache+solr) [apache](/questions/tagged/apache) **and** [solr](/questions/tagged/solr) or
- [tagged as](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache+httpclient) [apache](/questions/tagged/apache) **and** [httpclient](/questions/tagged/httpclient) (instead of [apache-commons-httpclient](/questions/tagged/apache-commons-httpclient), which is even mentioned in the [httpclient](/questions/tagged/httpclient) wiki)

Many other examples can be found when searching for questions [tagged as](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache+java) [apache](/questions/tagged/apache) and [java](/questions/tagged/java). Many/most of those are mistagged it seems.

My suggestion: rename [apache](/questions/tagged/apache) to [apache-http-server](/questions/tagged/apache-http-server) or something similar. Granted, a short tag name is a massive advantage, but "apache" simply doesn't precisely describe a single piece of software any more.

Comment: Sad (because I like the tag being just `Apache`) but true.

Comment: @Pekka: I know, but apart from some complicated logic like "discouarge the [tag:apache] tag when the [tag:java] tag is present" or something similar I can't think of another good solution to this problem.

Comment: My suggested rename: `apache` to `apache-httpd`. This is the short name used on http://httpd.apache.org/ while the long name is "Apache HTTP Server".

Comment: Does no-one else think this is a problem? It's getting to the point that almost every second question is getting wrongly tagged with Apache because the user is using some Apache project and just types "Apache <project>" into the tag line. Can we *please* rename this tag?

Comment: I'm in favor of renaming apache to apache-httpd.  I've been cleaning these up lately and it's a huge waste of time.

Answer (score 10):

I suggest we clean up the double-tagged questions (mentioned in the question) and then rename [apache](/questions/tagged/apache) to [apache-httpd](/questions/tagged/apache-httpd) (as Colin 't Hart suggested). Finally we'd need to blacklist [apache](/questions/tagged/apache).

Oh, and maybe blacklist [httpclient](/questions/tagged/httpclient) while we're at it (it even says not to use it in its tag wiki).

Comment: Bingo, action! Agree completely. I've already started with the double tagging by removing [tag:Apache] from unrelated questions, but they seem to come back faster than I can clean them.

Comment: And of course I completely agree with the proposed new tag name, it's the shortest we can come up with.

Comment: [tag:Microsoft] is also a valid tag, so then [tag:Apache] is just as valid. I'd blacklist both, they're both too meaningless.

Comment: @Colin'tHart: agreed, but putting too much in this request will just get it ignored ;-) I'd stay with what the question mentions for now. ([see this for the more general approach](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/199189/blacklist-the-microsoft-and-apple-tags)).