# How to split hyphenated tag-strings?

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms, synonym-request

I have found a tag named [unicode-string](/questions/tagged/unicode-string), which is used to categorize some questions which should properly have tags [unicode](/questions/tagged/unicode) and [strings](/questions/tagged/strings) on StackOverflow.
Most of those questions have at least one of the constituent tags, if not both.

Imho, the hyphenated tag should be replaced by those two tags, unless someone can explain how it conveys any additional information.

This leads to my main question: Is there any way to propose such a multi-tag-synonym, and how would one go about it?

Can and should StackExchange support such synonyms?
If no to both technical but not to the retagging, which way should the synonym go, or should it be retagged manually on a regular basis?

Anyway, I am a bit unsure about how to categorize this properly...

Comment: In my opinion never use hyphenated tags unless there is no base tag.

Comment: I don't believe there is a way to do this automatically, and I believe the scenario is rare so the utility of such a feature would be minimal.  Best suggestion is to retag the affected questions manually

Comment: @psubsee2003 If there is no possibility of such a synonym, should it be retagged and then a synonym to one of those two created? Because I fear otherwise someone will just recreate it (maybe inadvertently).

Comment: @Deduplicator after all of the questions are removed from the tag and it is cleaned up, there is no need for a synonym since the tag will be gone.  A synonym will be more confusing than anything simply because the tag doesn't directly match either tag.  It is a specific element of each tag almost equally.  If it gets recreated, then figuring out what to do would be in order then.

Comment: @psubsee2003 Can trusted users or moderators do that efficiently using their bulk-retagging tools, or must it be done manually for this specific case?

Comment: @Deduplicator 10K users can't (or at least I haven't found such a tool)... mods do have more tricks up their sleeves, but in I do not believe they have access to anything that would handle this appropriately.  The reasoning is retagging is often too much for an algorithm as human decision making is required on most questions

Comment: Related: [We should NOT have hybrid tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/190540/289691)